# Ruby on Rails 'link_to' method creates wrong link

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having issues with the `link_to` method in Rails. I have the routes established, but the urls aren't working correctly.

```
3000/gov_official => my root page

3000/gov_official/1 => desired show page url

3000/gov_official.1 => what I am getting...
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My code snippet:

[image]

Comment: Never post code as image.

Comment: What's the value of your `rake routes`?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in your routes instead of manually defining the index/show routes.

```
resource: :gov_official, only: [:get]
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably having an issue link_to, try this one.

```
<%= link_to gov.name, gov_official_path(id: gov.id) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

From my own experience, the problem is that Rails can't figure out which path are you trying to link to. Because, your resource is not in plural form `gov_officials`, you don't have 2 clearly separate paths:

1. `gov_officials_path` - takes 1 argument **format**. Generates: `gov_officials.format`.
2. `gov_official_path` - takes 1 argument **model**. Generates: `gov_officials/:id`

So, to solve your problem **the Rails way**, use pluralization of your resources correctly.